# Jump to source shortcut vs. context menu

Tags: android, android-studio, contextmenu, shortcut

as known from Eclipse, if I focus a resource id (R.menu.x, R.layout.x etc) in Android Studio 1.0, right click and select "Go to" -> "Declaration (F3)" I jump to corresponding xml file. So far so good. But if I use the shortcut, e.g. F3 as default or if I customize it like in Eclipse with "Cmd" + "Right mouse button" I jump to the R.java file instead.

Why is the shortcut behavior different to the context menu one?

By the way I'm using OSX.

Comment: In my case they (Cmd + B and cmd + rightClick) work identically : jump to layout xml file. OSX, AS 1.0, default settings

Answer (score 0):

I also recently moved from Eclipse to Android Studio. So i found it difficult with shortcuts in Studio. Then found the best way. Preferences/Settings in Studio->IDE Settings->KeyMap->Select Eclipse. Voila!!! All the shortcuts that you used in Eclipse would work now in Studio